# How to insert static block into header with local xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, local.xml

I have made a simple static block which is just an unordered list containing social links that I would like to place into my header. How would I go about inserting it into my header via local.xml? thanks

Answer (score 6):

To do so add the following code to your `local.xml` file under the `<default>` handle:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="cms/block" name="my_block">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>my_block</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Then in your `template/page/html/header.phtml` you can do

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_block'); ?>
```

This is assuming your static block identifier is `my_block` which is unlikely so you will have to replace this value with your static block id in the code I provided.

Comment: So you have to put it in both local xml and header.phtml? or can you do either

Comment: @OliTuck yep both